# How to pass -id parameter to get-process from pipeline?

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a `[pscustomobject]` with a property `id`. According to PowerShell documentation, the parameter '-id' can be passed through the pipeline using `ByPropertyName`. I discovered that the approach with `ForEach-Object` works (although I don't understand why), while the approach without `ForEach-Object` does not.

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{id=4444}
# doesn't work
$obj | get-process -id $_.id
# it works
$obj | foreach{get-process -id $_.id}
```

Apparently the "foreach" does the trick, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.4#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument) argument indicates that the parameter accepts input from a property of a pipeline object. The object property must have the same name or alias as the parameter.

The binding happens by pipeline already, you don't need to manually pass the argument, moreover, [`$_` (PSItem)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.4) is only automatically populated in the context of scriptblock and your second statement has no scriptblock.

```bash
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{ id = 4444 }
# works, the value of `id` is taken from pipeline
$obj | Get-Process
```

As to why the `ForEach-Object` example works, simply because you're passing the value of `id` property as argument to the `-Id` parameter, it is pretty much the same as:

```bash
Get-Process -Id $obj.Id
```